How to prevent Android Emulator from sending large amounts of data to the Internet
I'm using an Android Emulator (API 34, Emulator version 35.2.10-12414864) on a Mac (M1 Pro, Mac OS 14.6.1) and I noticed that it is sending an unusually large amount of data.
E.g. running for 30 minutes, it already sent about 1,57 GB

Any guidance to manage or fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: seems to be a local network transfer, perhaps between the emulator and ADB or Android Studio...

Are you running any app in background? Check in data usage in emulator settings for which app is using this much of data.

No, data usage not even close to the observed values.
